Copilot Free in Visual Studio Not Working
I was using GitHub Copilot, and after some time, it just stopped generating responses. When I send a prompt, it shows that it's "thinking" for a while, but then both the response and my original prompt disappear completely.
I suspect this might be because I hit the limit for Copilot Free, but I'm not entirely sure. There's no clear message indicating what the issue is. Has anyone else experienced this, and is it related to hitting the free-tier limit or something else?
